# How can we set time or delay of 5 seconds in dropdown sub menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we set time or delay of 5 seconds in dropdown.

Requirement are like this: When someone hover over main menu then its shows that submenu for 5 sec only when your mouse is away from main menu or sub menu.

For now i have increased the height of ul upto height of banner images so that it will not be hide untill you move your mouse out of that banner area.

Below is the site link: http://transitions.advisorproducts.com/home

and this is one reference site link : http://focusyou.com/home (my requirement are like this, but i don't want to copy this code, i want to implement in my own code)

Below is the js:

```
$(function()
{
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

You can test here : http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/KQAYT/2/

Comment: Do you know [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function()
{
    var timer = 0;
    $("ul.dropdown > li").hover(function()
    {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        $("ul.dropdown > li").removeClass("hover");
        $("ul.dropdown > li ul").css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function()
    {
        var link = $(this);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $(link).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',link).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }, 5000);
    });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
});
```

1. setTimeout functions will add a delay for a specified number of milliseconds.
2. this keyword will not work inside setTimeout function, so i have used a reference to value of this in variable link.

Here's the working example of code: http://jsfiddle.net/alokjain_lucky/KQAYT/

Comment: This one is more clear - if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
previously it is creating a little bit problem but now its 100% perfect as per my requirment :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to abstract this behavior and not deal with timers etc., then use this: 
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Otherwise just use a timer:

```
$(function()
{
    var hideTimer;
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul', this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); //this should fix the error you mentioned!
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function()
    {
        if(hideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(hideTimer);
            hideTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("hover");
                $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
});
```

I would definitely recommend the jquery hoverIntent plugin though, great abstraction for hovering intents, plus no manual timer management.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply your logic is perfect but i think their might be some problem with condition, Its is not working perfectly once i hover menu and remove mouse from that area submenu are still there and i think hidden functionality is not working perfectly because after hovering on all the menus all the sub menus are visible now.

Comment: +1 for hoverintent it works in a way that people find natural

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot :) your Ans also help me a lot it was awesome :)